# Angular: ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular

Estoy utilizando un componente de autosuggestion para Angular,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

funciona pero cuando reviso la consola me encuentro con que tira este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error me lo marca en el [data]="marcasListado"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A marcasListado la seteo en el onInit donde le asigno un array de objetos de marcas para enviar a la vista, al input del autocomplete

```
 export class EditarComponent implements OnInit {


    //atributos para el select autosuggestion de marcas
    marcasListado: Brand[]; 
    keyword = 'name';
    notFound: string = "No se encuentra marca";


  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private productosService: ProductosService,
    private marcasService: MarcasService,
  ) {
    this.producto = new Producto;
    this.selected = "";
    this.marcasListado = [];
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // busco producto
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.productoId = parseInt(params.productoId);
       this.buscarProducto(this.productoId);
   })
  
   // listado de marcas
   this.marcasService.getAll().subscribe((brands: Brand[]) => {
     this.marcasListado = brands;
   });   

  }
  
  async buscarProducto(productoId: number): Promise<any>{
    try{        

        const encontrado = await this.productosService.getById(this.productoId);

        console.log(encontrado);

        this.producto.id = encontrado.id;
        this.producto.brand.id = encontrado.brand.id;
        this.producto.brand.name = encontrado.brand.name;
        this.producto.name = encontrado.name;
        this.producto.code = encontrado.code;
        this.producto.quantity = encontrado.quantity;
        this.producto.price = encontrado.price;

        //seleccionado
        this.selected = encontrado.presentation;

    } catch(error){
      console.log('hay error');
      console.log(error);
    }    
  }    
    
}
```

No encuentro cual seria el problema